# Coriolis test problem

Tags: fluid-dynamics, testing

I have a eulerian hydrodynamic code, which I have recently implemented the Coriolis force in the integrator. Is there a standard test problem for the Coriolis force?

Since this isn't a Lagrangian code there is no tracking of fluid particles. Right now I am thinking about periodic boundary conditions and setting the entire box to constant density with an initial velocity and watching the entire box evolve. Thankfully since the force is only dependent on velocity and the box's orbital frequency, the medium should evolve homogeneously.

It would be nice to track an individual particle instead of just the velocity evolution of the entire box. If I created an over density, on a static background density, with a non-zero velocity it would be almost analogous. There are some obvious problems with that which make me unsure if it would be a clean test.

Comment: The Coriolis force can be thought of as a body force (like gravity) and techniques used to verify the correct implementation of gravity can be extended to deal with Coriolis effects (manufactured solutions come to mind).  

I'd just try a comparison with the exact solution of motion of a ball (in vacuum) in rotating coordinates.  You will run into numerical diffusion (as you seem to suggest) but the center of mass velocity and position should be quite close to the exact solution.